# Sorting two arrays in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I need to sort two arrays (the first one, ascending; and the 2nd one descending)

Here goes the code where the sorting is done: -

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)                      //1st array, ascending
{
    for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
    {
        if(array1[j]>array1[j+1])
        {
            int temp=array1[j];
            array1[j]=array1[j+1];
            array1[j+1]=temp;
        }
    }
}                                            //Over

for(int i=0;i<10;i++)                        //2nd, descending
{
    for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
    {
        if(array2[j]<array2[j+1])
        {
            int temp=array2[j];
            array2[j]=array2[j+1];
            array2[j+1]=temp;
        }
    }
}                                            //Over
```

When I try printing these, it screws up somewhere and I'm unable to pinpoint the problem in the code. Thanks..

Comment: What's wrong with `std::sort`?

Comment: What's the size of arrays? 10? 11?

Comment: "it screws up somewhere" -- Best description ever.

Comment: What does "screws us somewhere" mean? Does it crash?

Comment: do yourself a favor http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/

Comment: if you use `std::vector` you can do this `std::sort(array1.begin(),array1.end());`

Comment: How does the given code is related to the problem?

Comment: @Raxvan, `std::sort(std::begin(array1), std::end(array1))` is better.

Comment: Use [`std::sort(std::begin(array1), std::end(array1), comp)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) where `comp` is [`std::less`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less) (ascending) or [`std::greater`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater) (descending).

Comment: I'm sure I saw someone else post this earlier

Comment: Sorry for the vague description.. but I'm not sure if I can explain it (newbie). And I cant use methods for this question.

Comment: For a simple problem like this, you can always write out the results of each iteration on paper yourself!

Comment: Tried tracking it step by step.. couldn't figure

Comment: @Preformer: Then you didn't stick at it long enough.

Comment: I can always use different sorts. I posted this here because I'm curious about this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just had to limit the inner loop to <9.
The fixed code:

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)                        //1st array, ascending
{
    for(int j=0;j<9;j++)
    {
        if(array1[j]>array1[j+1])
        {
            int temp=array1[j];
            array1[j]=array1[j+1];
            array1[j+1]=temp;
        }
    }
}                                            //Over

for(int i=0;i<10;i++)                      //2nd array, descending
{
    for(int j=0;j<9;j++)
    {
        if(array2[j]<array2[j+1])
        {
            int temp=array2[j];
            array2[j]=array2[j+1];
            array2[j+1]=temp;
        }
    }
}                                        //Over
```

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

You can use C++ itself to sort (quite efficiently) arrays, using any valid rule you want. If you want it in ascending order, you can use the default variety, which automatically uses `<` effectively. If you want it in descending order, you just have to use the opposite comparison, the `>`.

Example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> makeAscending = {3,2,1};
    vector<int> makeDescending = {4,5,6};

    sort(begin(makeAscending), end(makeAscending)); // could pass less<int>() if you wanted
    sort(begin(makeDescending), end(makeDescending), greater<int>());

    // print to see answer
    copy(begin(makeAscending), end(makeAscending), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
    cout << endl;
    copy(begin(makeDescending), end(makeDescending), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
}
```

Just to be precise, a valid rule for sorting is one that produces a weak ordering of the items in the container. The Wikipedia page has the rules, but they are mostly this (calling any general "rule" the symbol < and x,y,z are items in your container):

1.) `x < x` is never true.

2.) If `x < y` is true that means `y < x` is false. (and if `x < y` is false and `y < x` is false, they are seen as "equal")

3.) if `x < y` is true and `y < z` is true then `x < z` is true.

Comment: Thanks, but as I already commented, I have to solve that particular question manually (for loop n all) so this wont help.